# Python string extraction: Extract part between two predefined strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

lets say I have a string like this:

```
"ID: 123 Name: Michael , ID: 124 Name: John"
```

I want to extract all of the ID's like a list which is the word between `"ID:"` and `"Name:"`

My desired output:

```
output = ['123', '124']
```

How can I do this most efficiently? Thank you very much=)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) here. You can extract *Number* between `'ID: number Name:`.

```
s=" ID: 123 Name: Michael , ID: 124 Name: John "
re.findall(r'ID: (\d+) Name',s)
# ['123', '124']
```

Regex pattern explanation `r'ID: (\d+) Name'` You can read about [`regex Syntax`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

- `\d+` is used to capture numbers
- `()` is used to capture the pattern enclosed between them.
- `re.findall` Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string. If one or more capturing groups are present in the pattern, return
  a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
  has more than one group.

I would suggest using a dictionary instead of storing details in a string.

```
details={'123':'Micheal','124':'John'}
```

Since every `ID` would be unique you can use it a key and `Name` as value corresponding to the key.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[ i for i in " ID: 123 Name: Michael , ID: 124 Name: John ".split() if i.isnumeric()]
```

gives the output:

```
['123', '124']
```